# When does the 'expected realization' of a stochastic process exist?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider a stochastic process $X_t$ (discrete or continuous time).
Under what conditions does there exist a process realization $X^{(\mathbf{t})}=\{X_t\}_{t\in[0,\infty)}$ such that: 
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\left(X^{(\mathbf{t})}\right)(t)=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}(X_t)?$$

I'm trying to think of $\mathbb{E}(X^{(\mathbf{t})})$ as a particular realization of the process itself, a sample path, potentially in some extension of the probability space.

**Example 1:**

Consider the 'coin flipping process' where each $X_n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is equally likely to be $0$ or $1$. Most process realizations are not convergent as there will be a $0$ or $1$ in the future with probability one. Any process that is eventually convergent is eventually constant $0$'s or $1$'s (a collection of paths which, in totality, is probability zero). However, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}(X_n)=1/2=\mathbb{E}(X_k), \ \forall k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Does it even make sense to ask what $\displaystyle\mathbb{E}\left(X^{(\mathbf{n})}\right)$ is? If there is some process realization $Y^{(\mathbf{n})}=\displaystyle\mathbb{E}\left(X^{(\mathbf{n})}\right)$ (potentially in some extension of the original probability space), then we can ask about $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Y^{(\mathbf{n})}_n$. It seems like $Y^{(\mathbf{n})}$ might simply be one of the sequences with 'deterministically' alternating $0$'s and $1$'s.

Alternatively, we could map all sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s to the interval $[0,1]$ by
$$f(X^{(\mathbf{n})})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{X^{(\mathbf{n})}_k}{2^k}.$$
Then, we have $\mathbb{E}\left(f(X^{(\mathbf{n})})\right)=1/2$, yes? Do uniqueness/one-to-one-ness issues matter here? Some squences get mapped to the same real number. If there are no issues, we get 
$$\mathbb{E}\left(f(X^{(\mathbf{n})})\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}(X_n)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

**Example 2:**

Consider another 'coin flipping process' where, with equal probability, $X_{n+1}=X_n/2$ or $X_n$. I think in this case, with probability one, both $\mathbb{E}(X_n)$ and $X_n$ converge to zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Regardless of what $\mathbb{E}\left(X^{(\mathbf{n})}\right)$ is, if it can be defined, intuitively, it should be a sequence of numbers with converges to zero.

Please feel free to suggest ways to make the question more clear or notation more standard.